# how can i solve this problem or find this file Connection.php in laravel when migrate

Tags: php, laravel, migrate

I got this error when I do any of migrate or key generate or any thing how can I fund this file or can solve

In Connection.php line 664:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 
'testyu.languages' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `languages` where
 `symbole` is null limit 1)
```

In Connection.php line 326:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 
1146 Table 'testyu.languages' doesn't exist
```

any idea

Comment: check any service provider you might calling query so its throwing error i guess.check Appservice provider but problem is languages table doesnt exist

Comment: This error simply says that the `languages` table does not exists in your database. There is no need to check services or Connection.php or aything else.